# Laravel, Controllers, APIs, Transformation to fit response into a Select Input

Tags: laravel, api-design

I have a Model called : Federation.

In my View, I load a Select Combo via AJAX from a API Call.

I share the same controller for the API and for the view dispatcher --> FederationController, I don't have a separed architecture between Front end and Back end ( like Full Angular or Full VueJS architecture), it's mixed.

So, basically, my Controller says:

```
if (Request::ajax()){ // This is an API call from JS
   return json;
else
   return view;
```

And it works well ( I may have a problem when I will include an Android app...)

Thing is in some case, I don't want the full json model, but just the info tu fill the Select input, in general, I do

```
federations->lists('name','id'), or with pluck, as lists has been deprecated.
```

Thing is I don't really know how to organize it, because my API is based on returning Full Models, this is OK, but this kind of transformation is quite frequent.

So, I should create a kind of transformToSelect($model) Method or use great lib like [Fractal](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/) to transform it, but I don't really know how to invoke without losing my endpoint.

In my routes.php, I have a group of routes like:

```
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'], function () { 
        Route::get("federations", 'FederationController@index');
        // All my APIs 
    });
```

And I'm glad with it, because it sticks with REST.
I could get a solution having my route like:

```
Route::get("federations", 'FederationController@getForCombo');
```

But soon, I will have a mess, so, I wish there were a simple an elegant solution to my problem...

Any idea how to solve it?